# Using STAT relation in CActiveDataProvider criteria

Tags: yii

This is my controller action

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

        //Supervisor non possono vedere brani OPEN
        //Gerard (manager) non puo' vedere OPEN/REJECTED/PROPOSED/CLOSED
        //Editor non puo' vedere APERTO/PROPOSTO/REJECTED se non suo


        $with = array(
            'propostoCount',
            'pubblicatoCount',
            'pendingCount',
            'apertoCount',
            'rifiutatoCount',
            'chiusiCount',
        );


        $condition = 'propostoCount=1 AND pubblicatoCount=1 AND pendingCount=1 AND rifiutatoCount=1 AND chiusiCount>0';         


        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Brano', array(
            'criteria'=>array(              
                'with'=>$with,
                'condition'=>$condition,
                'order'=>'id DESC',
            ),

            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>5,
            ),

        ));

        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }
```

And these are my relations in Brano Model:

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'proposto' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_PROPOSED, 'order'=>'ultimo_aggiornamento DESC'),
            'pubblicato' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_PUBLISHED, 'order'=>'ultimo_aggiornamento DESC'),
            'pending' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_PENDING, 'order'=>'ultimo_aggiornamento DESC'),
            'aperto' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_OPEN, 'order'=>'ultimo_aggiornamento DESC'),
            'rifiutato' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_REJECTED, 'order'=>'ultimo_aggiornamento DESC'),
            'chiusi' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_CLOSED, 'order'=>'ultimo_aggiornamento DESC'),

            'propostoCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_PROPOSED ),
            'pubblicatoCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_PUBLISHED ),
            'pendingCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_PENDING ),
            'apertoCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_OPEN ),
            'rifiutatoCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_REJECTED ),
            'chiusiCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'BranoVersione', 'brano_id', 'condition'=>'stato='.BranoVersione::STATUS_CLOSED ),
        );
    }
```

When I try to run it it says:

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'propostoCount' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `brano` `t` WHERE (propostoCount=1 AND pubblicatoCount=1 AND pendingCount=1 AND rifiutatoCount=1 AND chiusiCount>0)

Comment: I don't think you quite understand how relations work, you might want to look at the documentation [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr). In particular, see the section about using relations with paramaterized [named scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-named-scopes) as that might apply to what it seems like you are trying to do. You don't use relation names in the "condition" attributes and I don't believe it does anything to use more than one "with" if it's the same join. (Using "with" does the join in advance.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see what you're trying to do here, compare the `STAT` relations value in the query right?

I ran into this same issue, but `STAT` relations aren't implemented that way. They're pulled from the database in a seperate query so are only available for use within PHP not in the SQL itself.

If you want to have a condition using the `STAT` relationship, you'll have to redefine it inside the query as a full sub-select (or something depending on the query type).